# Prove or Disprove? $\log(n^n)$ is $\Theta(\log n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

I need help confirming that my way of proof is alright. This is my first class in algorithms so I just wanna know if I’m on the right track. :)

---

**Problem $\boldsymbol{\#1}$**

(a) $C(n) =\log(n^n)$ implies that $C(n)$ is $\Theta(\log n)$.

**Definition of Theta notation:** 
$f$ is of order $g$, writen “$f(x)$ is $\Theta(g(x))$”, if and only if there exist positive real numbers $A$, $B$ and a nonnegative real number $k$ such that: $$A|g(x)| \leq |f(x)| \leq B|g(x)| \text{ for all real number } x \geq k.$$

**Proof:** 
So in order for “$C(n) =\log(n^n)$ is $\Theta(\log n)$” to be true we must satisfy the following inequality for some $k$, $A$ and $B$:
$$A|\log n| \leq \log(n^n) \leq B|\log n| \text{ for all real number } x>9.$$
By rule of logs. and we can drop the abs. signs because it’s implies we are dealing with positive numbers:
$$A \log n \leq n \log n \leq B \log n; \\ A \leq n \leq B.$$
Looking at RHS equation let’s assume $n \geq 1$.

For $n \leq B$, there is no $B$ that can satisfy this inequality because $n$ can grow arbitrary large but $B$ remains a constant.

We don’t have to check the other side of the inequality because to be in $\Theta$ both sides must be true.

We also know by the L’Hopital’s rule that the rate of growth of $n \log n$ is much faster to be only at most $\log n$ so since it fails “$C(n)$ is $O(\log n)$” it can’t possibly be $\Theta(\log n)$ since another fact that must be true for “$C(n)$ is $O(\log n)$” to be true is:

$f(x)$ is $\Omega(g(x))$ and $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ if and only if $f(x)$ is $\Theta(g(x))$.

L’Hopital’s rule:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n^n)}{\log n} = \frac{n \require{cancel} \cancel{\log n}}{\cancel{\log n}} = n \to \infty.$$
The top function grows faster. So the statement is always false.

Comment: You really want to take the time to typeset your posts using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which is just $\LaTeX$ in the browser. I know it takes time, but the effort will result in more people willing to read your work, recognize your efforts, and participate in your efforts. In other words, your willingness to typeset all of this writing might be recognized and returned in kind by someone actually choosing to read it. It also makes the post more scalable on a larger variety of electronic interfaces.

Comment: Okay, thanks J.W. Perry. Will do. I'll delete this and do it in LaTeX. I'll just learn it, yeah so that they won't have to guess my handwriting correct? XD

Comment: I just caught this in review queue as a close vote, and thought I would let you know. I will abstain my vote. I know you are new, no harm done, stick around. :) You could probably just temporarily delete, then TeX it up, and then un-delete, the choice is yours. Note that learning the TeX is well worth your while. It was one of the more useful skills that I learned on my own as an adult.

Comment: Oh thank goodness, thank you J.W. Perry for abstaining your vote. I was under the impression that people around here were mean or something or really strict. I guess it's just because of the format of my answer. :/ I tried my best too. XD

Comment: There are a few meanies, but you will find in time, that some of the kindest human beings on the planet reside here. Put your effort in knowing that, I promise you will meet them. Also it will help if you keep a thick skin, but that is just good advice for life. :)

Comment: Thanks. :) You made me feel infinitely better. J.W.Perry

Comment: Your proof has *more* details than it needs, in my opinion: for example, violating the upper bound $\log n^n \le B \log n$ is enough to break $\Theta(\log n)$, so you don't need to mention the lower bound (after the actual definition). Also, "$n\le B$ for all sufficiently large $n$" is clearly false, and probably doesn't require as much explanation as you had. Finally, you say "l'Hopital's rule" but that isn't what you do. l'Hopital's rule is about using derivatives to find the limit of an indeterminate form - not a general phrase about limits of quotients.

Comment: Greg Martin, thanks. I was wordy because pretty much this is my first time tackling these types of problems. So how would you do it then? Should I just mention n <= B is clearly false therefore log(n^n) is not Theta(log n) as a conclusion, so I could be less wordy? Also in totality aside from L'Hopital's rule, which I will remove once I write this in LaTeX am I handling this problem correct proof wise, is my though process alright? :)

Answer (score 1):

$\log(n) \notin \Theta(\log(n^n))$

You can prove this fairly easy. If you know how logarithms work, you can do the following: $\log(n^n) = n\log(n)$ and that is obviously not in $\Theta(\log(n))$ since it grows $n$-times as fast.

$f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$ if and only if $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ and $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$.

But in this case $\log(n) \notin \Omega(n\log(n))$ (you can prove this from the definition).

You did this in your proof, so I guess you got the idea.